# Using PDO with INSERT (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've got

```
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `aliases` (`alias`, `domain`, `added`, `enabled`) VALUES (:alias, :domain, :added, :enabled)");
$sql->bindValue(':alias', $alias);
$sql->bindValue(':domain', $domain);
$sql->bindValue(':added', time());
$sql->bindValue(':enabled', 1);
$sql->execute();
//how do I test if it was added or #1062 - Duplicate entry '...' for key 'alias'
```

I assume that's correct.

My question is:
How do I test if it was added successfully?

Comment: you are missing the lines to assign values to :alias, :domain, :added and :enabled

Comment: Oh I forgot to copy them. I'll add them now

Comment: Would checking $sql->errorCode() work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the return value of `$sql->execute()`, like this:

```
if ($sql->execute()) {
    // Query succeeded.
} else {
    // Query failed.
    $errorcode = $sql->errorCode();
}
```

For more information, see [the documentation for PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) (the class of prepared statements).

Answer (score 2):

See the docs about [PDO Error handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) and this [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php#67194)

By default you have to check the return of execute. Details can then be found in [errorinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) and [errorcode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php)

```
if ($sql->execute === false) {    //check return, false on error
     var_dump($sql->errorinfo();  //array containing information on error
     die()
}
```

But I would recommened using PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION so that a [PDOException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) is thrown on error. This makes your code a bit neater. The basic information is provided by the exception's [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.tostring.php) but further information can be found (using an exception's normal methods, see link to docs above).

```
$db = new PDO( /* your connection string */ );
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
try {
    $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `aliases` (`alias`, `domain`, `added`, `enabled`) VALUES (:alias, :domain, :added, :enabled)");
    $sql->execute();
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;             //basic information is provided due to Exception::__toString()
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($stmt->errorCode() == "00000")  {
  // Query succeeded.   
} else {
  // Query failed.
  echo "Error: " . $stmt->errorCode();
}
```